# What is an engagement manager - what does (s)he do?

Tags: process, roles, definition, sales

Could anyone please give me a role description of an engagement manager? I think it should be the person internally responsible for getting a deal.

The more detailed the better. References are also welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a different experience and  perspective to what an engagement manager (EM) does and I expect the term means different things depending on context.

In my experience, on large projects where part of the work is outsourced to a third-party vendor, the EM is the person from the vendor organisation responsible for managing the relationship with the client and monitoring services delivery throughout the project. **His/her focus is on the management of the contractual relationship between client and vendor rather than the management of the project itself.**

Main responsibilities include:

- managing the relationship with the client throughout the project duration and acting as the main point of contact between client and vendor organisation;
- ensuring the services delivered by the vendor are conform to what has been contractually agreed between client and vendor and monitoring the delivery of said services against agreed schedule, quality, scope and budget;
- managing vendor resource planning and addressing resources performance issues;
- managing the financial aspects of the contract (billing for services, following-up on payments etc.);
- acting as the escalation point when issues arise with vendor's resources / services and managing any dispute or conflict;
- reporting internally within vendor organisation on project performance (services delivery, progress, economics, etc.).

A couple of additional notes (based on my experience):

- the EM is often not the person who got the deal (this is typically done by Business Development managers): the EM is concerned with the execution of the contract and although is ideally involved in the pre-sales stage, doesn't necessarily drive it. He/she however is often expected once the project has started to identify further business opportunities for services to the client.
- the EM is often not full-time on the project or physically present with the project team. He/she tends to get involved in a mediating capacity when problems arise and manage the contractual aspects of the services, not the actual day-to-day delivery. It is important for all parties to be clear up-front as to what the EM does and how he/she will actually be involved.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the term "engagement manager" in a discussion around the gamification.

Engagement Manager would be the person who plans and manages user engagement in the company's profile. She should be responsible for taking actions and activities in order to:

- call the user/customer attention
- plan user activities around the company (for example around products)
- maintain customer engagement (long, and short- therm) and loyalty
- keep the quality and joy of the engagement compared to the competition

It is growing in importance because of the rising impact of social media in the company's marketing campaigns. In larger companies, engagement manager could as well relate to a person who "manages" engagement of employees in their private life around the company.

Some googled links:

- [Microsoft's EM Role description](http://tinyurl.com/3tbaasa)
- [quite nice point of view on EM role](http://pmtips.net/engagement-management-project-management/)

Answer (score 0):

The word "engagement" or "engaging" is used, for example, for football players to "engage" with their fans. Football teams have to sell a lot of tickets every single game. The "engagement" action is done by players and members of the organization toward the clients/fans. In the science of marketing, there is a part responsible of making your clients long term customers. You give them rebates on the cost of the tickets; you give them a gift when they arrive at the stadium; you give them free tickets. You make their experience better for them to adopt your team and to sell more tickets, especially season tickets. But that is not engaging. When a football player "engage" he creates a closer relationship with a fan or a group of fans. It is all about the image of the team. Football players can "engage" in their community, for example, when they visit an hospital with sick children. They create a bound with the community. Football players are chosen especially when they have a talent in "engaging" with fans and with a community.